# Failed to enter configuration mode in Netmiko while trying to use send_config_set

Tags: python, netmiko

I'm new to Python and Netmiko. I;m trying to use netmiko to login to aruba switches. while i pass on some commands using send_config_set, it is erroring out saying "failed to enter configuration mode" am i missing anything here.

```
one solution was suggested to set "fast_cli to False" and global delay factor to 4 and even that did not work.
```

can someone help me with this pls?

````
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
network_device = {"host": "x.x.x.x",
                  "username": "admin",
                  "password": "password$",
                  "device_type": "aruba_os"}

with ConnectHandler(**network_device) as ssh_connect:
    print(ssh_connect.find_prompt())

    for vlan in range(1001,2000):
        config_commands = ['Vlan ' + str(vlan), 'name: Private_Vlan ' + str(vlan)]
        output = ssh_connect.send_config_set(config_commands)
        print(output)


```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vijayswaminathan/PycharmProjects/Taormina/switch_login.py", line 33, in <module>
    output = ssh_connect.send_config_set(config_commands)
  File "/Users/vijayswaminathan/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1876, in send_config_set
    output += self.config_mode(*cfg_mode_args)
  File "/Users/vijayswaminathan/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netmiko/aruba/aruba_ssh.py", line 52, in config_mode
    return super().config_mode(config_command=config_command, pattern=pattern)
  File "/Users/vijayswaminathan/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netmiko/cisco_base_connection.py", line 48, in config_mode
    return super().config_mode(
  File "/Users/vijayswaminathan/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1766, in config_mode
    raise ValueError("Failed to enter configuration mode.")
ValueError: Failed to enter configuration mode.

Process finished with exit code 1
````

I tried to run netmiko debug and looks like netmiko is issuing the commands correctly. Netmiko logs are:

```
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\r'
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: P2\-09
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: P2-09# 
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: P2\-09 P2-09# 
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'configure term\r'
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: P2\-09
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: 

DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: P2-09# 
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: P2\-09 
P2-09# 
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\r'
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: P2\-09
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: 
P2-09# 
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: P2\-09 
P2-09# 
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\r'
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: P2\-09
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: configure term
P2-09(config)# 
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: P2\-09 configure term
P2-09(config)# 
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'exit\r'
```

Comment: Kindly ignore. with device type as "hp_procurve" it works. thanks to this thread. https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/issues/1928

Comment: Use `aruba_procurve` instead of `aruba_os`

Comment: Thanks Aruba_procurve helped. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sample code I wrote below. It will be enough to update the prompt section.

```
try:
    network_device = {
        'device_type': 'aruba_os', 'ip': x.x.x.x, 'username':
            username, 'password': password, }
    net_connect = Netmiko(**network_device)
    print("success enter")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return

prompt_aruba_fnk = net_connect.find_prompt()
hostname_fnk = prompt_aruba_fnk.strip("<" + ">")
print(hostname_fnk)
net_connect.send_command_timing("enable")
net_connect.send_command_timing("undo smart")
output = net_connect.send_command_timing("config")
print("entered config mode")
net_connect.send_command_timing("acl 2010 ")
net_connect.send_command_timing("save")

print("islem tamamlandi")
with open("MDU_OK_2.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(nodeip + "\n")
    f.close()

net_connect.disconnect()
```